# Session storage not giving actual value

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I'm trying to console.log a value taken from an input from session storage but it gives me
" [object HTMLInputElement " but not the actual value of the input what can be done? Here's my code

```
let us = document.getElementById('us')
sessionStorage.setItem("user",us)
setTimeout(function() {
let h = sessionStorage.getItem("user")
console.log(h)
}, 200);
```

Comment: What are you *storing*?

Comment: It's a string from an input

Comment: Obviously it isn't, or you would be getting a string back.

Comment: I get a string with the exact value when logging it directly :/ so I'm pretty sure it's a string ,  I'm not sure why this is happening I used . value after it and now it's giving me an empty message

Comment: `document.getElementById('us')` returns an `HTMLInputElement`. If you're getting a blank value back when storing the element's `value`, and there's actually a value in it, then perhaps you're saving it at the wrong point--there's no way to know without enough of an example to understand how your code actually *works*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Huseyint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5363605/huseyint) said, you must use `<HTMLInputElement>.value` to get the value of the input field. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#:%7E:text=submitting%20a%20form.-,value,-string%3A%20Returns%20/%20Sets). For example, your code would be rewritten like this:

```js
const us = document.getElementById('us');
sessionStorage.setItem('user', us.value);
const h = sessionStorage.getItem('user');
console.log(h);
```

Or if you want to save all of the properties you could do something like this:

```js
const us = document.getElementById('us');
sessionStorage.setItem('user', us);
const h = sessionStorage.getItem('user').value;
console.log(h);
```

Either one should work. Also, note that `setItem()` isn't a promise so you don't need the `setTimeout`.

**Hoped this helped!**

Answer (score 1):

Your script is working correctly but document.getElementById('us') is html element, you store HTML element. I think you need value or something, you write or change like this document.getElementById('us').value or what you need to do.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to add that , now with this I'm getting nothing but an empty log? Id say it's an empty message

Comment: Himm.. I give to value 'test' for let us and it work. Can you debug your code? Or You can copy your code and give let us = 'test' in devtools console. You will see working. I think debug your code and you will understand what you forgetting